# Unity texture shows UV border

Tags: unity, textures, uv-mapping

I have a photogrammetry asset whose UV is, like most photogrammetry assets, a mess.

And when I import this asset into Unity, the texture shows clear borders at the place where the UV is not connected, forming many "patches":

[image]

Compare to the same region displayed in Maya (Surface Shader):

[image]

What caused this and is there a way to fix it?

(this is in Unity 2021.3.22f1, URP, default settings)

Comment: Can you use an untextured material, to check whether this may be partly due to normals/lighting?

Comment: @DMGregory Ahh I think you solved it, a blank shader does not have this effect, but adding a normal map makes it appear. I changed the normal setting from tangent to object and it disappeared. Thank you :D

Comment: Try posting an answer showing what setting you changed to fix the problem, which could help future searchers struggling with similar issues. It sounds like you have an object space normal map - showing an image of that map can help make this easier to diagnose, as tangent space normal maps usually have a distinctive pale blue look, while object space maps have a much larger colour contrast range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@DMGregory in the comment pointed out what to check and I was able to find and solve this problem.

My normal map was generated by photogrammetry software and looked like this:

[image]

In Shader Graph (since this one is using a shader graph), select normal, and in Graph Inspector, the `Fragment Normal Space` has 3 options. Mine was defaulted to `Tangent`, and after changing it to `Object`, the patches disappeared.

[image]

Comment: Hm, that does look like a tangent space normal map. Can you show what nodes you're using to compute the value that gets routed to that Normal pin? It's possible you converted to object space somewhere upstream from what we can see.

Comment: @DMGregory upstream of the `Normal` input is a `.jpg` texture. That map was set to `Tangent` space by default and I have not changed it. The map was generated by the photogrammetry software developed by other people at my institution so I am not sure how it is implemented.

Comment: That may suggest a problem in how this mesh's tangents are defined.